# can you take absolute value of a column and then find the sum in power bi using DAX

Tags: powerbi, sum, absolute-value

I am new to power bi, and I have

[image]

I want to take the absolute value of the column, and then add it together, ie `sum(abs(Column1))`, but when I create a measure to do this, I get an error:
[image]

yet, if I update the measure to `abs(sum(Column1))`, I get the value of `3`, not `9`.

Does anyone know a way around this issue

Answer (score 0):

Can create a measure like this

```
Measure = 
var _new_table = ADDCOLUMNS('table (2)', 
                            "new_col", abs('Table (2)'[Column1]))
return
CALCULATE(SUMX(_new_table, [new_col]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Create this measure:

```
AbsoluteSum = 

VAR Positive = CALCULATE(SUM('table (2)'[Column1]), 'table (2)'[Column1] > 0) 
VAR Negative = CALCULATE(SUM('table (2)'[Column1]), 'table (2)'[Column1] < 0) * -1

RETURN
Positive + Negative
```